# how to pass empty string to a input element in katalon studio

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am doing automating the test cases for my web page using Katalon Studio. My problem is that I don't know how to pass or send an empty string to an input element, here I want my test case to fail so. I tried with set text and sendkeys keywords, getting following error

> TC_2_testcase_for_fail-Copy FAILED because (of) (Stack trace:
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:
>   WebUiBuiltInKeywords for class: Script1539673712359   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
>     at Script1539673712359.run(Script1539673712359.groovy:33)   at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:183)     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:108)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:264)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:256)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:200)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:99)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:90)
>     at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>     at TempTestCase1539675610128.run(TempTestCase1539675610128.groovy:22)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
>     at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:507)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:653)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:384)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:370)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:129)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:109)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131) )

Comment: Please, share your test case code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just send the empty string as a parameter:

```
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/input element'), '')
```

Comment: I am passing empty value through variable, inturn is binding to colunm from the excel sheet as blank.                     
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_site/input_form-control ng-untouche'), site_name)

Comment: Can you share how is `site_name` bound to excel sheet.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After saving, it just keep the previous inputed data